# How do I forcefully uninstall any module having content?

Tags: entities, 8, installation

I want to uninstall the Field module, but this module can not be uninstalled; when I try, I get the following message.

> Field API to add fields to entities like nodes and users. Machine
>   name: field Version: 8.0.6 Required by: TextNodeAdmin ToolbarAdmin
>   Toolbar Extra ToolsFileOptionsAggregator (disabled) ImageAccelerated
>   Mobile Pages (AMP) (disabled)Custom BlockBook (disabled)Text
>   EditorCKEditorCommentInterface TranslationConfiguration Translation
>   (disabled)

How do I forcefully uninstall any module that is having dependency or content inside, for example the Node module, the Views module, or any entity having content in it?

I tried using `\Drupal::service('module_installer')->uninstall(['admin_toolbar']);` but then my site breaks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to uninstall this crucial module?

Comment: I'm just experimenting things as how one can remove all traces of any installed module by some piece of code.

Comment: Doing it with the UI with a minimal installation, I ran into a [dead end](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gDCNV.jpg). I can't uninstall Text, which in turn it won't allow me to uninstall Field. Also, as you can tell, it appears Field is the super module/heart of Drupal Core.

Comment: Its not about jss one module - Fields, this is a generic question, I can't figure out as how to uninstall any module which is built with entity concept and entity having content. For example, I made any custom content entity type and add content into it. Now I can not uninstall my custom module until and unless I delete all content or truncate module specific db table. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @SugandhKhanna Yes, that's what you would expect to happen. No, you can't remove a module on which existing parts of the system depends. The only way to remove a part of the system on which a second part of the system depends, is to remove that second part first. It's what dependencies _are_. If you could just remove the field system when there are existing fields, or remove the module that provides content without removing the content, then they wouldn't be dependencies any more. They'd be optional. And in the context of fields/nodes/etc, that wouldn't make sense

Comment: @Clive I'm going through this link right now, https://www.drupal.org/node/2409673, not sure about this, but I think a little possibility exists.

Comment: @clive can you help me figure out what's wrong with this function `function uninstall(array $module_list, $uninstall_dependents = TRUE) {` [public function ModuleInstaller::uninstall][1]


  [1]: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleInstaller.php/function/ModuleInstaller%3A%3Auninstall/8.2.x      It is not uninstalling modules with dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, I made any custom content entity type and add content
>   into it. Now I can not uninstall my custom module until and unless I
>   delete all content or truncate module specific db table – [Sugandh Khanna](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206122/how-to-forcefully-uninstall-any-module-having-content-in-it-ex-fields-nodes#comment-250791).

Unfortunately, in Drupal 8 you can't disable a module, like you can in Drupal 7.

In Drupal 7 you need to disable the module first, which means all module related code stays in DB. Then, if you wanted, you Uninstall to remove everything from DB.

In Drupal 8 the only option is to uninstall the module, which means you have to destroy all traces of your module from the Database. You cannot just disable the module anymore.

Also, to uninstall Flag [(as in your comment here)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206122/how-do-i-forcefully-uninstall-any-module-having-content/206128#comment-250795), you have to uninstall dependencies first, then and only then, it will allow you to uninstall Flag. Because if module X depends on Flag and somehow you removed flag, it will totally screw up module X, X becomes useless, module X is nothing without Flag. Therefore you need to remove module X first, then and only then it will allow you to remove Flag.

For more info: [Why can't I uninstall modules in Drupal 8? (Explained)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2225029)

Issue: [Disabled modules are broken beyond repair so the "disable" functionality needs to be removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/1199946)

Comment: Thanks @No Sssweat. So the final conclusion is we can not uninstall dependencies. Or It is just impossible to uninstall Flag

Comment: @SugandhKhanna you have to uninstall dependencies first, then and only then, it will allow you to uninstall Flag. Because if module X depends on Flag and somehow you removed flag, it will totally screw up module X, X becomes useless, module X is nothing without Flag. Therefore you need to remove module X first, then and only then it will allow you to remove Flag.